# How return json object response after SELECT data with parameter on WHERE using PL/SQL Stored Procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle19c

Here is the Stored Procedure code as follows:
request_id is parsed using a simple JSON Parser. I can't run **SELECT** statement that returns JSON_OBJECT or JSON_ARRAY.

```
create or replace NONEDITIONABLE PROCEDURE MY_UPDATE_COMPANY
(
    IN_DATA IN VARCHAR2,
    OUT_MSG OUT VARCHAR2
)
AS
    json_data JSON_OBJECT_T;
    comp_body JSON_OBJECT_T;
    
    request_id  NUMBER (18,0);
    r_company SYS.company_request%ROWTYPE;
    
BEGIN
    json_data := JSON_OBJECT_T.PARSE(IN_DATA);
    
    request_id := json_data.get_Number('id');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('ID: ' || TO_CHAR(request_id));
    
    SELECT * INTO r_company
    FROM SYS.company_request
    WHERE id = request_id;
    
    dbms_output.put_line( r_company.company_name || ', email: ' || r_company.email );

    -- How to convert it to JSON_OBJECT_T as saving comp_body
    
    -- OUT_MSG := comp_body; This is what I want.

END MY_UPDATE_COMPANY;
```